# why introducing sleep causes producer consumer to wait?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm just learning to use the C++ threading library. 
If anyone is curious - my code is just a modified version in a tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=13dFggo4t_I&t=6m45s

I wrote a simple producer/consumer code. I tried to introduce a sleep to make the producer and consumer in lockstep fashion, so item is consumed as soon as it is produced. But making the producer waits causes some deadlock. I couldn't figure out why.
Can you please help me point out what I'm missing in the code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 10

std::mutex mu;
std::condition_variable full,empty;
std::vector<int> vec;
int i=0;
std::chrono::milliseconds slp(10);

void produce()
{
  while (i < 2*BUFFER_SIZE) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(mu);
    full.wait(locker, [] {return vec.size() != BUFFER_SIZE;});
    vec.push_back(i++);
    empty.notify_one();
    //std::this_thread::sleep_for(slp);   <--- introducing this causes program to hang.
  }
}

void consume()
{
  while(!vec.empty()) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(mu);
    empty.wait(locker, [] {return !vec.empty();});
    std::cout << "Consumed:" << vec.back() <<"\n";
    vec.pop_back();
    full.notify_one();
  }
}

int main() {
  vec.reserve(BUFFER_SIZE*2);
  std::thread producer(produce), consumer(consume);
  producer.join();
  consumer.join();
  return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

```
void produce()
{
  while (i < 2*BUFFER_SIZE) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(mu);
    full.wait(locker, [] {return vec.size() != BUFFER_SIZE;});
    vec.push_back(i++);
    locker.unlock();
    empty.notify_one();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(slp);
  }
}

void consume()
{
  while(!vec.empty()) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(mu);
    empty.wait(locker, [] {return !vec.empty();});
    std::cout << "Consumed:" << vec.back() <<"\n";
    vec.pop_back();
    locker.unlock();
    full.notify_one();
  }
}
```

Comment: You are sleeping while holding the mutex...

Comment: `consume` is accessing the vector outside the lock, which can't be right. And `consume` will exit if it starts after something is added to the vector, which will deadlock your producer.

Comment: Pardon any naivete around the C++ threading library, but I don't see anywhere where you release the mutex either...

Comment: @RyanJ, `std::unique_lock` will do it when it goes out of scope.

Comment: Ok, I figured. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: Alan, why do you say consume is accessing vector outside the lock? The unique_lock should lock the mutex until it goes out of the scope right?

Comment: Thanks T.C. I've made the change to unlock before going to sleep, still the code has a deadlock. Edited the original post to include the EDITed code.

Comment: What happens if the full condition variable is modified to check for `vec.size() >= BUFFER_SIZE`?

Comment: Also, the way I learned producer / consumer with this approach is that the producer waits for empty on the quantity reaching and/or exceeding the max amount.  Then signals the full condition prior to unlocking the mutex.  Similarly, the consumer waits on the full condition being zero or smaller and signals empty prior to unlocking the mutex.  Accessing the vector prior to locking is to be avoided.  Use an infinite loop in the consumer.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of problems:

1. The consumer is accessing `vec` without the mutex held:

   ```
   while(!vec.empty()) {
   ```

   This is easily addressed by ensuring that all acceses to `vec` are "inside" the mutex.
2. If the consumer gets ahead of the producer and manages to empty `vec`, it will exit early. You can fix this by using some other mechanism to indicate completion.
3. You are performing some processing/io/sleep with the mutex held, reducing possible concurrency. ideally you should only hold the mutex while accessing shared state.

```
const unsigned BUFFER_SIZE = 10;

std::mutex mu;
std::condition_variable full,empty;
std::vector<int> vec;
const std::chrono::milliseconds slp(10);

auto done = false;

void produce()
{
  for (auto i = 0u; i < 2 * BUFFER_SIZE; ++i) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(mu);
    full.wait(locker, [] {return vec.size() < BUFFER_SIZE;});
    auto was_empty = vec.empty();
    vec.push_back(i);
    locker.unlock();

    // Only notify if the buffer was empty before the push_back
    if (was_empty) {
      empty.notify_all();
    }

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(slp);
  }
}

void consume()
{
  for (;;) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(mu);
    while (vec.empty()) {
      if (done) {
        return;
      }
      empty.wait(locker);
    }

    auto was_full = vec.size() >= BUFFER_SIZE;
    auto value = vec.back();
    vec.pop_back();
    locker.unlock();

    if (was_full) {
      full.notify_all();
    }
    std::cout << "Consumed: " << value << '\n';
  }
}

int main() {
  vec.reserve(BUFFER_SIZE*2);
  std::thread producer(produce), consumer(consume);
  producer.join();

  // Produce some more
  producer = std::thread(produce);
  producer.join();

  // Produce A LOT more
  std::vector<std::thread> many_producers(8);
  for (auto&& t : many_producers) {
      t = std::thread(produce);
  }
  for (auto && t : many_producers) {
      t.join();
  }

  // Tell consumer we are done producing
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mu);
    done = true;
  }
  empty.notify_one();
  consumer.join();
}
```

[See it live at Coliru.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7fbbe17576ae22ba)

Comment: Thanks Casey. Appreciate helping me understand. I also had a couple of questions 1) Removing the condition check "vec.empty()" outside the locking and adding "++num_consumed; if (num_consumed ==  2*BUFFER_SIZE) return;" solves my problem. But can you tell me why the code would deadlock earlier rather than exiting early. 2) In your code, what's the significance of "auto && t". It works with "auto &t" as well, which I understand as copy by reference but what does "&&" mean? Here's my modified code http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/92940aff7fbda73e

Comment: @Nura 1) The deadlock happens if the consumer exits early and the producer fills the queue and then waits forever for the queue to not be full. 2) It makes no difference in this instance, but `auto&&` is more general than `auto&`. `auto&` can only bind to lvalues, whereas `auto&&` can bind to both lvalues and rvalues. I tend to use `auto&&` by default when I want to modify the elements in the loop and `auto const&` when I don't. The updated program looks correct to me.